# Prove Taylor expansion $(\mathrm{exp}\,tX)(\mathrm{exp}\,tY)=\mathrm{exp}(t(X+Y)+\frac{1}{2}t^2[X,Y]+o(t^2))$

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, lie-derivative

This is an exercise from John Lee’s book Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, GTM218, chapter 20. It says

> For Lie group $G$ and two vector fields $X,Y\in \mathrm{Lie}(G)$, we have
>   $$(\mathrm{exp}\,tX)(\mathrm{exp}\,tY)=\mathrm{exp}(t(X+Y)+\frac{1}{2}t^2[X,Y]+o(t^2))$$
>   for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ near origin.

I can explain the first term $t(X+Y)$ by differentiating $\varphi(t)=\mathrm{exp}^{-1}((\mathrm{exp}\,tX)(\mathrm{exp}\,tY))$ at $t=0$, but have trouble calculating higher differentials. I know it’s a special form of the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula, but it should be solved within the scope of the basic knowledge of Lie group and exponential map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expansion can be derived easily when $G$ is a matrix Lie group, since then we have an explicit formula for $\exp$. My question concerns whether it is true for arbitrary Lie groups. Notice the local nature of the problem: the expansion holds when $|t|$ is sufficiently small. Thus we may invoke Lie's theorems which tell us that any Lie group is locally isomorphic to a matrix Lie group. I think this is sufficient to derive the general case. Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: I think it is better if we do not invoke Lie's theorems. I think it should be done through the techniques of the chapter the exercise is included in. Although, even I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: expand both sides to $O(t^2)$ and compare